# Python interactive project configuration and deployment

Tags: python, configuration

I'm looking for a tool for setting up programming environment, testing, deployment, documentation generation in an interactive fashion. Such that developers won't need to look for the information in readme or project code every time they need to perform one of these tasks.

For example:

```
$ make env
>>> Create virtual environment with Python 3.6.4 at 'venv' [y/n]?
$ y
>>> Which Tensorflow version to use (recommended 1.13.1 or 2.0.0)?
$ 2.0.0
>>> Do you need docker support [y/n]?
$ n
>>> ...
```

Or say documentation generation and deployment:

```
make docs
>>> Building documentation...
>>> Upload documentation to my_project.github.io [y/n]?
$ y
```

Are there any tools or libraries that can help to develop such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a job for [cookie cutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can set up project templates, and those templates can ask the user to make choices during set up.